# Remove hours and extract only month and year

Tags: pandas

I try to keep only month and year in this df. I tried several solutions but it is not working. Can you help me ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do not post images of data as it makes it impossible to help you in your specific case. Do this instead. Post the result of ```df.head(20).to_dict()``` inside your question.

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to do this (as you post no data, you'll need to adapt this to your case):

```
from datetime import datetime


datetime_object = datetime.now()
print(datetime_object)

2021-11-30 15:57:20.812209
```

And to get the year and month do this:

```
new_date_month= datetime_object.month
print(new_date_month)
new_date_year = datetime_object.year
print(new_date_year)


11
2021
```

If you need them as new columns in you df:

```
df['year']=datetime_object.year
df['Month']=datetime_object.month
```

Note that if your column is not a datetime, this will not work. Given to format of date you hve you will need to do this first:

```
st = '2021-11-30 15:57:20.812209'

datetime.strptime(st, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: If this is your accepted answer, do mark it as such so it may disappear from the list of unanswered questions. Happy coding!